# Chrome is lagging when using CSS background-size:cover in scrolling background image

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I've got a background image that is being scrolled in my page section. However, in order to support different device screens for the same quality of the background image, I used the css property `background-size:cover` and it is okay. The only problem goes with Google Chrome that is lagging when I use this property. Removing this property returns the chrome to its good performance.

What should I do? I have searched the net for this problem and I got some solutions using JQUERY. But, I want to do it using pure CSS if possible.

Comment: Show the code, or your question is most likely to get closed.

Comment: If you don't understand the problem, that doesn't mean that the question has to be closed. This is not some thing to be shown. That is a browser BUG. But, if you want to see what is going on, you can look at the website: http://mitenadesign.com/en/ the very beginning background with google chrome

Comment: We are not debating about chrome bugs dude. We are talking about a problem that needs a trick or something to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem when using several images with big resolution, and I added to the element:

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

It's not the best trick in all situations, but it can improve the performance. It will use the GPU to process the render.

Check this [explanation](https://coderwall.com/p/j5udlw/improve-scroll-performance-of-chrome-when-using-background-size-cover) and [this one](https://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/) for more info.

Comment: brilliant trick!